# C++ pass enum to object constructor

Tags: c++, eclipse, constructor, enums

Say I have the following:

```
Foo::Foo() {
value = 25; //default constructor...
}

Foo::Foo(Enum bar) {
value = (int)bar; //purpose is to allow an integer to take enum constant's integer value.
}
```

from...

```
enum Enum 
{
A = 25,
B = 50,
}

class Foo 
{
public:
    Foo();
    Foo(Enum bar);
private:
int value;
}
```

Yet, if I do the following:

```
Enum bar = A; //A = 25

Foo * foo = new Foo(A); //error: "undefined reference to Foo::Foo(Enum)"
```

This is in Eclipse CDT 3.6. Why is this happening? Is there anything I can do about this to solve the problem?

Comment: Foo header file is included ?

Comment: enum Enum?  Worst naming ever!

Comment: you forgot to implement Foo::Foo(Enum); ? Say like the .cpp didn't get compiled properly?

Comment: @tp1 

No, the .cpp is identical to the .h file in terms of method signatures.

Comment: in what file is `Foo::Foo(Enum bar)` implemented?  Is that file included in the project file (i.e., is it actually being compiled)?

Comment: It's in the main file, and the header path is of absolute reference.

Comment: @Cechner

If it will make things easier, I can just copy source code in here.

Comment: yeah, it would help to see all the code.  But if your definition is in the main file, and you're using it in the main file, why don't you just put the declaration in there as well? EDIT: sounds like Mark is helping you with your link error below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you forgot to link `foo.C` into your final application.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite following. What do you mean, exactly?

Comment: +1.  @Holland: If you put the implementation of `Foo::Foo(Enum)` in a separate file - say `foo.c++`, then the normal compiler behaviour if you compile that file is to produce `foo.o`.  You then need to tell the compiler to link `foo.o` when compiling the file containing `main()`.  On UNIX/Linux, you'd normally write a `Makefile` to do this, but I'm not sure what Eclipse expects.

Comment: @Tony

Thanks for your assistance, Tony. My Eclipse project is actually setup to use a Makefile to do the compiling. Is there any quick snippet I could write within the Makefile which you know of that could do this?

Comment: @Holland: at absolute simplest, you want `app: <tab> app.c++ foo.o` on one line, `<tab> g++ -o app app.c++ foo.o` on the next.

Answer (score 4):

After fixing a few syntax errors (extra `,` in `Enum` definition, missing `;` after `Enum` and `Foo` definitions), your code was run-able in `gcc`. Check here: http://www.ideone.com/GZdNM

I don't really understand what you're trying to do with the `enum`, but for sure, calling it `Enum` is probably not a great idea...

Comment: That was just an example name. The real Enum name is just "BoostAmount". The idea is to pass the enum value to the constructor, and an integer field takes on the integer value the enum represents. My header file is included via absolute path, so I'm not sure how it works for you but it doesn't for me. If there are any questions I can answer, I'd be happy to.